How do I keep a TKinter window open after playing audio using pydub?
I'm building a basic text to audio app using python.When I play an audio file after taking an input from a user and clicking a button, the window closes after the audio file is played.
app = CTk()
app.title("Text to Morse Code")
app.geometry("600x400")


def gui_handler():
    def input_to_morse():
        morse_code = text_to_morse(entry.get())
        morse_audio = morse_to_audio(morse_code)

        threading.Thread(target=play, args=(morse_audio,)).start()

        print("Hello")

    gen_morse_button = CTkButton(app, text="Generate Morse Code", command=input_to_morse)
    entry = CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="Enter text to be converted")

    app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=40, pady=20, sticky="ew")
    gen_morse_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=40, pady=20, sticky="ew")




gui_handler()
app.mainloop()

This is the exit code for when the window closes.
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV)

I looked this up and it says some sort of segmentation error but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried using simple audio where I export the file from pydub and played it using simple audio but it's the same issue.
Edit : This is the morse_to_audio function
# Audio objects
dash = AudioSegment.from_file("./audio/beep.wav", format="wav")[:200]
dot = dash[:50]
short_gap = AudioSegment.silent(duration=100)
medium_gap = AudioSegment.silent(duration=200)
long_gap = AudioSegment.silent(duration=500)

def morse_to_audio(morse_code: list):
    """
    Converts a given list of morse code values and returns an audio file.
    :param morse_code: List of Morse code values depicted in "." "-"
    :return: Audio of Morse code being played.
    """
    morse_audio = AudioSegment.empty()
    for i, letter in enumerate(morse_code):
        if letter == " ":
            morse_audio += long_gap
        else:
            for j, symbol in enumerate(letter):
                if symbol == ".":
                    morse_audio += dot
                elif symbol == "-":
                    morse_audio += dash
                # if the symbol isn't the last symbol in a letter add a short gap
                if j < len(letter) - 1:
                    morse_audio += short_gap
            # if there is a next letter, and it isn't a space add a medium gap
            if i + 1 < len(morse_code) and morse_code[i + 1] != " ":
                morse_audio += medium_gap
    return morse_audio


Where did this morse_to_audio() function come from?  Perhaps it's generating corrupted data, that crashes the player after the end of the sound.

@jasonharper Thank you for the reply. I've edited the question and added the details.

If your application crashes after playing the audio, then it is most likely caused by the function play().  What is play()?

@acw1668 play( ) is the default playback function provided by the pydub library.

Then you need to find out which player is used internally by pydub.  The code for using ffplay internally has issue.

See related pydub issue.

Since pydub try to use simpleaudio, pyaudio and ffplay in that order, I would suggest to install pyaudio to fix the issue (hopefully).

@acw1668 Thank you for the suggestion. I actually tried installing all 3 before posting this. No luck. I was mainly hoping that there's some problem or a bit of code I'm missing with my implementation. The code does run and the sound does play, it just exits after it plays. If I didn't look up the exit code I would've thought it was the default behavior.
One workaround I have found is using pygame to play the audio after exporting is using pydub. But using a game module just for this one task seems problematic.

Try removing/uninstalling simpleaudio.
